# Magento 2.4.5: How to get Stripe payment information object in Observer class or otherwise

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, payment

With the upgrade to Magento 2.4.5 from 2.4.2, the old code in an observer class in a custom module to get information about Stripe Payment isn't working any more. It looks like Magento event sales_order_place_after isn't able to help with retrieving payment information. I tried several other events including  `sales_order_load_after sales_order_save_before sales_order_save_after sales_order_delete_before sales_order_delete_after and checkout_submit_all_after`.

Below is a part of the test program:

```
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
// Initial code to Bootstrap Magento 2 ends here

/*************************************************************************************************/
$date = $timezone->date();
// If one needs to diplay date in the formate of Ymd use 'Ymd'
$current_store_time = $date->format('Ymd H:i:s');

echo "<body>";
echo "**********************************************Magento Store Time : " . $current_store_time . "**********************************<br><br>";

// Sanitize the $_GET[] value
// redirect if the message parameter is invalid.
if (isset($_GET["order_id"])) {
    if (htmlspecialchars($_GET["order_id"]) == "invalid_id") {
        echo "Please ensure to enter the valid order ID by replacing invalid_id` with valid order ID in the URL";
        exit;
    }
}

// Sanitize the $_GET[] value
// Create an object of the order loaded with the $order_id passed as query string.
$orderId = htmlspecialchars($_GET["order_id"]);
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementID($orderId);

if ($order->getEntityId()) {
    echo "*********************************************Get Order Information: " . '*************************************************<br>';
    echo "Entity ID: " . $order->getEntityId() . '<br>';
    echo "Increment ID: " . $order->getIncrementId() . '<br>';
    echo "State: " . $order->getState() . '<br>';
    echo "Status: " . $order->getStatus() . '<br>';
    echo "Store ID: " . $order->getStoreId() . '<br>';
    echo "Grand Total: " . $order->getGrandTotal() . '<br>';
    echo "SubTotal: " . $order->getSubtotal() . '<br>';
    echo "Total Quantity" . $order->getTotalQtyOrdered() . '<br>';
    echo "Currency Code: " . $order->getOrderCurrencyCode() . '<br><br>';
    echo "Discout Applied: " . $order->getDiscountAmount() . '<br><br>';

    // Get Customer Information from the Order
    echo "Get Customer Information: " . "<br>";
    echo "Customer Email : " . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '<br><br>';

    echo "<br><b>**********************Testing with getAllVisibleItems() function call************</b><br>";
    //error_log(print_r($order->getAllVisibleItems()));
    $orderItems = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
        echo ("SKU = " . $orderItem->getSku() . "<br>");
        echo ("Name = " . $orderItem->getName() . "<br>");
        echo ("Price = " . $orderItem->getPrice() . "<br>");
        echo ("Qty = " . $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() . "<br>");
    }
    
    echo "<br>";

    // Get Order Payment Information
    echo "Get Payment Information: " . "<br>";
    $payment = $order->getPayment();
    $stripePayment = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment');
    $this->logger->debug("CC Last 4 digits " . $stripePayment->getCcLast4());
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Can you share the solution please?